# Why is Kotlin’s ArrayDeque a concrete class without an interface?

Tags: kotlin, collections

Of course, I can use the whole Java standard library as long as I stay on the JVM, but quite often Kotlin offers equivalent classes, sometimes shadowing Java’s classes (and using them behind my back). As such, Kotlin offers an `ArrayDeque` to replace Java’s `ArrayDeque`.

Now, the good old `java.util.ArrayDeque`, being in line with the other collection classes, implements the interface `java.util.Deque` (it’s actually one of four such implementations in `java.util`. That is usually considered good practice, if you just care for a Deque you should not need to know whether it is implemented using an array or a list.

However, the new-fangled `kotlin.collections.ArrayDeque` (where actually the package name is redundant, since it is accessible without) has no interface it implements, apart from `MutableList`, which is too generic.

I don’t want to trigger opinion-based answers here, even if I can already imagine a few of them. Rather, I wonder if there may exist a hard technical reason to decide against using a strategy used in other places of the Kotlin standard library itself.

Comment: Haha, I noticed exactly the same problem today. Did you maybe worked on today's Advent of Code task? :-) And answering your question: please note there is no `Deque` in the Kotlin stdlib, so `ArrayDeque` can't implement it. I don't know why they decided to skip `Deque`, but maybe they concluded it is redundant as `MutableList` can do the same as `Deque`. So `Deque` would only provide information about the performance characteristics and usually in Kotlin/Java performance is provided by implementations, while interfaces provide functionality. But I don't know if that was their reasoning.

Comment: There's no clues in the [Git history](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commits/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/ArrayDeque.kt) or [the ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21327), but you could ask in the comments.

Comment: One possible answer: there aren't any really competitive alternate implementations of Deque.  LinkedList exists, but ArrayDeque is better in practically every way.

Comment: A Deque is also something whose extra features you typically only use locally because you’re using it for optimization reasons. Not the sort of features you want to expose publicly with an interface, which in this case is generally used to provide some encapsulation.

Comment: A deque is a queue with symmetry, or like a stack with two ends, or a list where insertion and deletion at both ends are fast. Why would you consider that a local optimization? It is quite a useful and very general data structure. Maybe it’s less commonly used than others. But such are trees etc.